# Hyperledger Fabric. Is it possible to deploy more than one chaincode to the same channel?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Is it possible to deploy two different chaincodes to the same channel in Hyperledger fabric

Comment: I tried it and it's working; **however**, it's creating _different_ ledger for each chaincode even if it is in the same channel!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. And its possible to deploy the same chaincode to 2 or more channels. You can even deploy the same chaincode to the same channel if you use a different name.

Comment: But why do it will have different ledger for each chaincode. I thought the ledger, according to the documentation, is related to channel.

Comment: No. 1 chaincode contains 1 ledger. If you deploy the same chaincode implementation again using a different name, then you get 2 ledgers.

Comment: Note that by default, 1 channel will contain one ledger. However, in the case that multiple chaincodes are installed on a single channel, each chaincode will result in creation of a separate ledger (i.e. one ledger per chaincode )

Comment: In practice, it seems like you all are correct - a new chaincode creates a new ledger, but [this](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peers/peers.html#multiple-ledgers) doc contradicts that.  Also, Gari's answer [here](https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/fabric/topic/23751751) is confusing: "One chaincode cannot directly read or update the state of another chaincode" I'm guessing he means "ledger".

Answer (score 3):

when inspect into the block structure, I find a 'Chaincode Name' field in block, and I suppose that:

- One channel has one ledger([offcial doc](https://byfn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ledger.html))
- One channel can have two or more chaincodes
- The block generated by different chaincode(we can simplely think so) will be stored in the same one ledger
- The field 'Chaincode Name' in block will distinguish it's generated from which chaincode

Answer (score 2):

jworthington answer is correct but i want to clear some things from comments.

- One channel means one ledger. ([official doc](https://byfn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ledger.html))
- Every chaincode have separated "view" on ledger (I visualize it as every key in db has chaincode name prefix and chaincode can access
  only specific keys with same prefix as its name).
- You can invoke read/write of second chaincode from first one and that will make only one blockchain transaction (at condition that chaincodes are on same channel/ledger, if they are not, write operation will be ignored)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how much is changed over the years, but I share information based on version 2.x.

1. Ledger is associated with the channel, not with the Chaincode. Even a peer can have a ledger without any Chaincode installed. https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peers/peers.html#multiple-ledgers

   - P1 is Peer
   - L1 & L2 are ledgers
   - S1, S2, and S3 are Chaincodes

[image]

2. There isn’t a fixed relationship between the number of ledgers a peer has and the number of Chaincodes that can access that ledger. A peer might have many Chaincodes and many ledgers available to it.
   https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peers/peers.html#multiple-chaincodes

   - P1 is Peer
   - L1 & L2 are ledgers
   - S1, S2, and S3 are Chaincodes
     [image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can deploy multiple chaincodes to the same channel with different chaincode ID.
Each chaincode will have separate ledger in channel, we can consider this as namespace.
One chaincode can not read/update other channel ledger directly.

However, fabric shim package provides "InvokeChaincode" functionality to call another chaincode to read/update it's ledger.

`stub.InvokeChaincode("anotherCCName", chainCodeArgs, "channelName")`

Comment: Will it directly fetch data from different ledger or will this process completes whole transaction flow (Proposal->Endorsement->Ordering->Commiting) ?