# Can a single peer run 2 different chaincode

Tags: linux, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to chaincode something so just have a question that can a single peer run 2 different chaincodes?

So need your help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyperledger Fabric. Is it possible to deploy more than one chaincode to the same channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731706/hyperledger-fabric-is-it-possible-to-deploy-more-than-one-chaincode-to-the-same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, peer can have more than one chaincode installed and instantiated. Moreover for some case this is actually vital, for example if you would like to have a chaincode `foo` too call chaincode `bar`, you **have** install both these chaincodes on same peer. (Of course chaincodes have to be instantiated).